# New Line definition for HTTP/1.1 headers

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, http-1.1

I have an embedded system that makes a HTTP POST request, however I know that the headers must have a format.

In this case I have this request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\n
Host: 192.168.1.15\n
Connection: close\n
Content-Length: 44\n
Content-Type: application/json\n
\n
{\n
"command": "snapPicture",\n
"selfTimer": 0\n
}
```

I want to avoid any kind of error while I send this request.

1. Strictly talking, is it correct use **`\n`** to tell `new line` or should be **`\r\n`**?
2. Any suggestion about this request format?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Many servers will return 400 Bad request if you use only the line feed (\n) or only carriage return (\r) char.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use `\r\n` to separate headers, also to separate the body from the header section. See [RFC 7230 (Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing), section 3.  Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3):

> ```
> HTTP-message   = start-line
> ```

```
                  *( header-field CRLF )
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
```

`CRLF` being `\r\n`.

Whether the rest of the request is valid, especially the body, depends on the server you send it to.